# Weird artifacts with transparent png background-image in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, png, background-image, retina-display

I'm trying to create a pattern with a png with a transparent background. It works fine both on Firefox and Safari, but on Chrome it's displaying with some white space in between.

The code to reproduce the issue is quite simple:

```
div {
  background: url('http://vps97368.ovh.net/montessori.it/wp-content/themes/montessori/images/pattern-bg.png');
  height: 500px;
}

<div>blabla</div>
```

And I've created a pen to show it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPGOyx

The pattern should display simple parallel diagonal lines, but on Chrome I see them like this:

[image: pattern screenshot]

I'm experiencing the issue on a retina display. Not sure about others.

Answer (score 0):

Make the image bigger. I used 25x25 for this one:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNmVXQ

```
div {
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/haven-images/pattern-bg.png');
  height: 500px;
}
```